# WPF - Need to drag in text from notepad and then call a method

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a textbox on a WPF app that I want to be able to drag text into from an outside application (notepad++).  The PreviewDrop handler works great but when I go to retrieve the text from the text box after the handler is called (myTxtBox.Text) all I get is an empty string.  As soon as i drop the text into the textbox, i want the handler to fire and call another method that will do something with the text input that is being dropped.  but its firing too fast. any suggestions?

my handler method

```
 private void myTxtBox_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
 {
     string itemID = myTxtBox.Text.Trim();
 }
```

xaml of the text box

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTxtBox" Height="23" Margin="5,61,5,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" LostFocus="btnLookup_Click" Drop="myTxtBox_Drop" KeyDown="myTxtBox_KeyDown" AllowDrop="True"  PreviewDrop="myTxtBox_Drop" />
```

Comment: how do you drag from NotePad anyway?

Comment: highlight the text and drag it over

Comment: interesting the standard notepad doesn't seem to let you "drag" anything, it just tries to highlight again.  i can do it in Word etc, but I'd like to know how your NotePad is doing this.

Comment: sorry i failed to mention that im using notepad ++

Comment: It looks like you're using the same handler for both the preview and drop finished events, which is probably screwing things up.

Comment: @WasGoodDone No even if i remove the Drop handler i still get the same result.  And i started out using just Drop, which never fired.  So I added PreviewDrop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to get your dropped text:

```
string itemID = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString().Trim();
```

Comment: no problem.  i was tripping trying to figure out how to drap and drop in regular notepad lol